# Kurdyka Lojasiewicz property Intuition

Tags: reference-request, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Recently, I am learning Kurdyka-Lojasiewicz (KL) inequality in the context of nonconvex-nonsmooth optimization. That is, in the context of the minimization of $f$, i.e.,
$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x).
$$
However, I don't really see what would be an intuition behind the KL inequality.

Let me state the version of KL that I am reading.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$. 
>   For any $x \in \text{dom}(f)$, 
>   the Frechet subdifferential of $f$ at $x$ is 
>   $$
> \hat{\partial} f(x) = \left\{v \in \mathbb{R}^n : \liminf_{y \ne x, y \to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x) - \langle v, y-x\rangle }{\|y-x\|} \ge 0 \right\},
> $$
>   and the limiting-subdifferential at $x \in \text{dom}(f)$ is defined to be
>   $$
> \partial f(x) = \left\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n : \exists x^k \to x, f(x^k) \to f(x), v^k \in \hat{\partial} f(x^k) \to v \right\}.
> $$
>   We say $f$ satisfies the KL property at $x^* \in \text{dom}(\partial f)$
>   if there exist $\eta \in (0,\infty]$, a neighborhood $U$ of $x^*$
>   and a continuous concave function $\phi:[0,\eta) \to \mathbb{R}_+$ such that
>   $$
> (i)\hspace{0.2cm} \phi(0) = 0, \quad (ii) \hspace{0.2cm}\phi \in C^1(0,\eta),
> \quad (iii) \hspace{0.2cm} \phi'(s) > 0, \forall s \in (0,\eta),
> $$
>   and (iv) For all $x \in U_\eta:= U\cap \{z \in \mathbb{R}^n: f(x^*) < f(z) < f(x^*) + \eta\}$, the KL inequality holds
>   $$
> \phi'(f(x)-f(x^*))\text{dist}(0,\partial f(x)) \ge 1.
> $$

**Here is my interpretation:**

- $\hat{\partial} f(x)$: It is a generalized notion of differentiation (local convexity) of $f$ at $x$.
- $\partial f(x)$: To ensure the closeness of $\hat{\partial} f(x)$, the notion of the Frechet subdifferential is extended to the limiting-subdifferential.
- $x^* \in \text{dom}(\partial f)$: I understand this as follows: $x^* \in \text{dom}(\partial f)$ if $\partial f(x) \ne \emptyset$. 
  This is because there might be $x \in \text{dom}(f)$ such that 
  for any convergent sequence $x^k \to x$, $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{j=k}^\infty \hat{\partial}f(x^j) = \emptyset$, i.e., $\partial f(x) = \emptyset$.
- $U$ and $\eta \in (0,\infty]$: This indicates that the KL property is a local property which only conerns a neighborhood of $x^*$ where $f$ is controlled within $(f(x^*), f(x^*) + \eta)$.
- Concave function $\phi$: By (i)-(iii), $\phi$ is a non-negative, continuously differentiable and increasing function in $(0,\eta)$.
  Also, $\phi(ax + (1-a)y) \ge a\phi(x) + (1-a)\phi(y)$.
- (iv): To be honest, I am not sure how to interprete this inequality. If I just think of $\text{dist}(0,\partial f(x)) = \|\nabla f(x)\| \ne 0$ (assuming $f$ is differentiable), (iv) becomes 
  $$
  \phi'(f(x) - f(x^*)) \ge \frac{1}{\|\nabla f(x)\|}.
  $$
  Since $x \in U_\eta$, $0 < f(x) - f(x^*) < \eta$. 
  Thus, the KL inequality shows the behavior of $\phi'(z)$ in $(0,\eta)$, i.e.,
  how fast $\phi$ changes in $(0,\eta)$ through $f$.
  And the inequality says that $\phi$ has to increase at least with the rate of 
  $\frac{1}{\|\nabla f(x)\|}$.

More importantly, I don't see how and why the KL property is a key assumption in the proof of convergence of iterative methods.
Naively speaking, it seems to me that all we want is to find a point $x^* \in \text{dom}(f)$ such that $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$ or $\approx 0$ (assuming $f$ is differentiable).

Any comments/answers/references will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To gain intuition about KL it might help to look at the smooth formulation:
$$
|| \nabla (\phi\circ f)(x) || \ge 1,
$$
(locally). The function $\phi$ is sometimes called a "desingularization function". This just means that by composing $f$ with $\phi$ it can be made *sharp* (looks like the absolute values function around $0$). So in some sense the function should not be too flat around the critical point. The same intuition is also evident from the Lojasiewicz inequality:
$$
  (f(x)-f(\bar{x}))^\theta \le C || \nabla f ||,
$$
where $\theta \in (0,1)$ and $C>0$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

- I recommend *Proximal alternating linearized minimization for nonconvex and nonsmooth problems* by Bolte et al. What happens in this paper is basically the sequence generated by the proposed algorithm has finite length property, i.e., $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty|z^{k+1}-z^k|<\infty$$ thanks to KL. And this is a big deal because finite length property means your sequence converges really fast.
- Yes, KL is a local property. A good start to understand KL is to play with functions on the line. You can try to verify the KL property of $x\mapsto e^x$, $x\mapsto x^2$ and $$x\mapsto\begin{cases}\exp{(-1/x^2)}\sin(1/x),x\neq0;\\0,x=0.\end{cases}$$.